# Increasing post view count automatically

Tags: count, views

I am testing a ranking system for posts, and I'd like help with the below:

Upon publishing a new post, I'd like the post view count to immediately have a random number between 829 and 1013 added to it.

Could you please tell me how I can do that? If you offer any code, kindly let me know exactly where to put it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using custom field for counting post views?

Comment: Just to add what @Roberthue is asking. Usually the post view counters that is used are automatically available as a custom field in the post edit screen. If you can't see it, go to screen options and enable custom fields. From there, when a post is published, you can manually add any figure that you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automatically add a custom field to each new post on publish (on change status to publish). And then set it's value to a random number between 829 and 1013.

Here is the function that will do just that.

```
// Create custom field on post publish
function wpse_custom_field_on_publish( $new, $old, $post ) {

  if ( $new == 'publish' && $old != 'publish' && !get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views', true ) ) {
    add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views', rand(829, 1013), true );
  }

}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_custom_field_on_publish', 10, 3 );
```

In above code, `post_views` is the name of the custom field that we are using to count post views. You should change it to yours before using it in your theme.

Just FYI, this will go in `functions.php` file.

Comment: Here is part of the code from functions.php


`This is function gets the post views and display it in admin panel.

if ( !function_exists( 'getPostViews' ) ) {
    function getPostViews( $postID ){
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key,` 

`


Can you tell what the name of the custom field is? Is it `post_views_count`?

Comment: Your code works! I didn't want a new custom field so I changed `add_post_meta` to `update_post_meta` and `post_views` to `post_views_count`, was that fine to do?

Any other changes you recommend?

Thank you!

Comment: I am glad it worked out as you wanted :)

Comment: Hello Robert! It's been a few years. The code just stopped working with the last Wordpress update. How can I update it for today's Wordpress? Thank you!